# common question structures?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I'm creating an AI app that understands the user's sentence. I'm currently working on questions, and I'm wondering what are some common question structures?
I know  questions commonly start with: auxiliary + subject + verb.

If this is a question for english language learners, please move it.

Comment: There are a number of different structures. Yes/No questions perform subject-auxiliary inversion, wh-questions are yes/no questions that move an additional wh-word before the auxiliary, tag questions are inverted auxiliary plus subject as an end of sentence tag, indirect questions are phrases like _I wonder if you could tell me_ (there are lots), embedded questions are non-inverted wh-questions that are not intended as questions, but as complement clauses. That's a good sample for starts.

Comment: "I'm currently working on questions, and I'm wondering what are some common question structures?" Is that a question? Is it a statement? "I'm currently working on questions and wondering what some common question structures **are.** " is what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorely tempted to resort to Regular Expressions here, although I am far from being an expert in that discipline

I think there are two basic forms of question in English.

**1. Six "W" Questions (or questions that invite explanation, facts, or motivation):**

Who|What|When|Where|Why|How followed by a verb, typically forms of "to be", "to do", or "to have", followed by the subject of the question, or that which is to be responded to.

Examples:

Who are you?  What is that?  Why did you do that?  How do I fly?  When did he say that?  Where is my cheese?

Verbs other than "to be", "to do" or to have" are sometimes used with "Why", such as "Why ask me?" or "Why paint this wall?"

How is frequently followed by a compound interrogative phrase (How long/easy/stupid/...).

**2. Questions that begin with a verb followed by a pronoun or pronominal, typically eliciting "yes/no" responses, and frequently begin with the verbs "to be", "to do" and "to have".  Although "can/could", "will/would" and "should" are used as well:**

Examples:

Is this a good time?  Do you want to go?  Have you had a good time?  Will you give me that blanket?  Should I keep it?  Would you please be quiet?  Can I have a cheeseburger?

*Credit to @JohnLawler for some assistance with this answer. He gave it free to me in the form of a comment!  Generous chap.*

Comment: Note that every type 1 question is a type 2 question with a wh-word at the beginning of it. _How_ frequently gets followed by a compound interrogative phrase (_How long/easy/stupid/..._). And you forgot _whether_ -- it's the wh-word for yes/no questions, used only in embedded questions. As for all the verb order stuff, that's standard for every [verb phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf).

Comment: Whether my answer covers all bases is a matter for debate, and I am not claiming that it is absolutely complete.  There, that's not a question.  Wait a minute, that's not a question!  Maybe it's too early in the morning, but I can't seem to come up with "whether" in a question.  Please elaborate @JohnLawler!

Comment: Just elaborating the common English question structures. That's what the question is ostensibly about.